# File browser window in Visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, path, explorer

I am new to Visual Studio. I want to have a window which takes a part of the screen in the program. And explores the files and returns the current path of the file to a point in memory. How can it be done? is there is a special function for this purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From VS2010 onward, it supports all such environments.
I'm using VS2010

> New Project > MFC Application Wizard > Application Type Select
>   Optional Point, Project style - [Windows Explorer]